# Ports not exposing properly?

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service, azure-container-instances

My ports in a container app are not being exposed properly.. 
I get this docker run command
`docker run -d -p 0:3000 --name ############# -e`

Shouldn't the -p command be `-p 3000:3000`

Comment: What Service do you use and maybe I can give more help.

Comment: Do you solve the issue?

Answer (score 1):

Azure Web App for Container is just a kind in Azure Web App. And Azure Web App just expose the port 80(HTTP) and 443(HTTPS) to the Internet. The logs will just show you the command like this:

```
docker run -d -p 25762:80 --name azurenginx_0 -e WEBSITES_ENABLE_APP_SERVICE_STORAGE=false -e WEBSITE_SITE_NAME=azurenginx -e WEBSITE_AUTH_ENABLED=False -e PORT=80 -e WEBSITE_ROLE_INSTANCE_ID=0 -e WEBSITE_INSTANCE_ID=93ad2e7cf8572308af1ea47b5a6125d6b6778911630249caca8d58ef84d9937b nginx
```

Or

```
docker run -d -p 25762:443 --name azurenginx_0 -e WEBSITES_ENABLE_APP_SERVICE_STORAGE=false -e WEBSITE_SITE_NAME=azurenginx -e WEBSITE_AUTH_ENABLED=False -e PORT=80 -e WEBSITE_ROLE_INSTANCE_ID=0 -e WEBSITE_INSTANCE_ID=93ad2e7cf8572308af1ea47b5a6125d6b6778911630249caca8d58ef84d9937b nginx
```

If you use the Azure Container Instance, it seems you cannot see the command `docker run` from the logs. And the result will just like this:

[image]